# Why is yup "when" value always undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

My project has **Yup 0.32.11** with **Formik 2.2.9**, and I am trying to use the **Yup.mixed().when(...)** method to control a validation message based on a sibling field. The value of the sibling field being passed into the when(...) method is always undefined and I can't figure out why.

Specifically, I want my State field validation required error message to display "State is required" when the Country field is "US"/empty, and display "Province is required" when the Country field is anything else.

Sample codesandbox to illustrate the problem, including all the snippets below, is [here](https://lbdzg1.csb.app/).

Partial definition of the form:

```js
<Formik
      initialValues={{
        name: "",
        mailingAddress: {
          line: "",
          city: "",
          state: "",
          country: ""
        }
      }}
      validationSchema={ValidationSchema}
      ...
>
```

Here are 4 different variations of the validation schema that I have attempted, all of them behave as if the sibling field (Country) is undefined:

```js
const ValidationSchema = Yup.object({
  name: Yup.string().required(),
  mailingAddress: Yup.object({
    line: Yup.string().required(),
    city: Yup.string().required(),
    country: Yup.string().required(),
    //=== attempt 1 ... always returns province ===
    state: Yup.mixed().when("mailingAddress.country", {
      is: "US",
      then: Yup.string().trim().required(stateMsg),
      otherwise: Yup.string().trim().required(provinceMsg)
    })
    //=== attempt 2 ... always returns state ===
    // state: Yup.mixed().when("mailingAddress.country", {
    //   is: (value: string) => (value === undefined || value === "" || value === "US"),
    //   then: Yup.string().trim().required(stateMsg),
    //   otherwise: Yup.string().trim().required(provinceMsg)
    // })
    //=== attempt 3 ... always returns state ===
    // state: Yup.mixed().when("mailingAddress.country", {
    //   is: (value: string) => {
    //       return (value === undefined || value === "" || value === "US");
    //   },
    //   then: Yup.string().trim().required(stateMsg),
    //   otherwise: Yup.string().trim().required(provinceMsg)
    // })
    //=== attempt 4 ... always returns state ===
    // state: Yup.mixed().when("mailingAddress.country", (value, context) => {
    //   if (value === undefined || value === "" || value === "US") {
    //     return Yup.string().trim().required(stateMsg);
    //   } else {
    //     return Yup.string().trim().required(provinceMsg);
    //   }
    // })
    //=== the end ===
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround using **test** instead of **when**, but it requires multiple passes at the data unfortunately, so still hoping for a better answer.

```js
state: Yup.string().trim()
    .test("mailingAddressState-US", stateMsg, (value, context) => {
        let state = value || "";
        let country = context.parent.country || "";
        return (country !== "US" || state > "");
    })
    .test("mailingAddressState-nonUS", provinceMsg, (value, context) => {
        let state = value || "";
        let country = context.parent.country || "";
        return (country === "US" || state > "");
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with Yup validation recently where field that I refer to in the `.when()` is in a upper level (not in the parent even upper) and this seems to be the reason why you get undefined when referring to the field. But using `.when('$values.yourFieldInUpperLevel', {...})` it resolved the issue perfectly for me. Hope this helps anyone else or even myself in the future :))

```
 state: Yup.mixed().when("$values.mailingAddress.country", {
   is: "US",
   then: Yup.string().trim().required(stateMsg),
   otherwise: Yup.string().trim().required(provinceMsg)
 })
```